# connection between modules and a page on a backbone application

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I'm developing an application with this structure

- App

  - Pages

    - Profile
    - Account
    - etc...
  - Modules

    - nameOfModule
    - nameOfModule
    - etc

In the `Pages` directory I've got all the different pages in the application, switching between these pages will cause reloads.

In each of these pages directories, for example `Profile`, I've got 3 files(may differ)

- router.js
- main.js
- app.js

`main.js` is called using requireJS and the only thing it does in set some paths for the dependencies and then it just calls the `initialize()` located in `app.js` wich in turn simply initializes the router in `router.js`.

My problem is, how and where do I connect the modules to the actual page?
Lets say I've got a few modules that are supposed to show up on the `Profile` page, lets call them `Module1`, `Module2` and `Module3`, where do I organize these modules for the page?

It feels wrong to organize these kind of things in the router? Where do I decide wich modules I use and where they go?

Comment: Maybe my understanding of a module is off. As I see it modules, in my case, are a collection of a few files like a view a model and a collectionview file maybe a css file etc that all serve one purpose, like rendering a form for signing up as a member or something.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using Marionette's Module to help you

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.module.md#starting-and-stopping-modules

Comment: Yeah i've taken that into account, yet my question remains. Where, or How, do i manage these modules into a page. And what do I include in a module? Is a module a `div` containing a list of users or is the module only the list of users? Or am I all wrong?

Comment: A module is a logical breakdown. The best idea to grab the concept of module is in reference to gmail. In gmail, the email view is a module and the contact view can be consider as another module. Hope this helps.

Comment: well, from what I've heard a module can be even smaller like the sidebar, or the listing of mails or the top bar at gmail for example. Defining a whole page as a module seems kind of redundant since it's already "defined" as a page?